# Fill grid view with data from my WAMP server

Tags: android, wampserver

I have this XML file which has a grid view

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            app:layout_scrollInterpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/app_bar_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/action_poster"
                android:transitionName="typeImage"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">



            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="368dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="275dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">

                <GridView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="80dp"
                    android:columnWidth="80dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                    android:stretchMode="columnWidth">

                </GridView>

            </RelativeLayout>



    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Aand here is each item of the grid:

```
class GridViewcustomadapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    Context context;


    public GridViewcustomadapter(Context context) {
        super(context, 0);
        this.context=context;
    }

    public int getCount(){
        return 24;
    }
```

How can I fill this grid with data from my tables in WAMP server which has table has an image and title?

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
**SO is not** a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service
___We try to fix your code, we do not write your code___

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to learn how to make a HTTP request to get data from either local or remote server. There is alot of awesome library such as Retrofit, Android volley , OKHTTP which make HTTP request easier.

1. [Volley](https://github.com/google/volley)
2. [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)
3. [OKHTTP](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)

If you don't understand why you need to make HTTP request, it basically getting or sending data from a web server. So if you make a request to your own mamp server you will get all yours `HTML` code of that specific page.

For **how to fill your gridview with the data from your tables in wamp server**. You need to consider make another file which will return `JSON` format of your image for example

```
{
    title:"Stackoverflow",
    image:"https://www.example.com/stackoverflow.png"
}
```

Try to not parse `HTML` code because it is kinda headache although there is library call [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) which make parse `XML` alot easier but still if you have a choice try to make your server return `JSON` or `XML`.